# Interpreting binary data as float

Tags: c, floating-point

I have an external hardware meter that would send measured voltage values through a TCP connection as a floating point value. I am writing a C code to capture this data. The first code I wrote is as follows:

```
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define PORT 5843 


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){ 

struct sockaddr_in address; 
int sock = 0;
int valread; 

struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 
    //data_points* data = malloc(sizeof(data_points)); 
if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) { 
    printf("\n Socket creation error \n"); 
    return -1; 
} 

memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr)); 

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 

if(inet_pton(AF_INET, "130.127.88.141", &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0){ 
    printf("\nInvalid address/ Address not supported \n"); 
    return -1; 
} 

if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){ 
    printf("\nConnection Failed \n"); 
    return -1; 
} 

float data;
valread = read( sock , (void*) &data, sizeof(float));
printf("value: %f\n", data);

return 0; 
}
```

This code is an almost copy of [this geek-to-geek](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-cc/) code. But when I run this code I get a value as follows:

```
 ./client 
 value: -0.000000
```

Which is an unacceptable value. So to test the value I get, I modified the data receiving part as follows:

```
unsigned char data[4];
valread = read( sock , (void*) data, sizeof(float)); 
printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]);
```

Which prints:

```
./client 
65, 49, 110, 152
```

This I converted into a float value manually as follows:

```
 65  = 01000001
 49  = 00110001
 110 = 01101110
 152 = 10011000
```

concatenating them together gives:

```
01000001001100010110111010011000
```

which, when interpreted as a IEEE 754 float gives 11.0895 which is the actual value the meter sends. 
Why doesn't my initial code give this value? How do I convert it? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Step 1 when viewing FP values as part of debug.  Do not use `printf("value: %f\n", data);`,  Use `"%e"` or `"%a"`.  They are more informative.

Comment: "Why doesn't my initial code give this value?"  It depends on endian of the float (and other factors: encoding, width, etc.).  Try reversing the bytes of the float, then print.

Comment: Are you *sure* you need to send the data in floating-point form?  Chances are good that an integer-based fixed-point representation would serve your needs at least as well, and be easier to work with to boot.

Comment: @chux Thanks for the %e and %a suggestion. I'll use that. And is there any standard function which would reverse the bits for me? A google search won't produce any good results.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes, your suggestion makes sense. Thank you! But as I mentioned, the input is generated by a hardware meter. And I cannot find any settings where I could set this in it. So I'd have to stick with floating points at least for the time being.

Comment: @NewComer Research _reverse bytes_ as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53529251/interpreting-binary-data-as-float?noredirect=1#comment93927332_53529251), not _reverse bits_.

Comment: @NewComer What were your expected results and actual results when using `"%e"` and `"%a"`?